# Lua - Convert XML datetime into UTC timestamp

Tags: datetime, lua, timestamp, datetime-conversion

I do not have much experience with `lua` and could not accomplish a simple (I think) task:

Given a String that contains a timestamp (parsed from an XML file), how could I convert it into TIMESTAMP in UTC format using a `lua script`?

```
my_date = "2019-11-21T22:35:03.332+02:00"
```

Basically I'd like to write a function/script that when passing such a String, I'd get back an empty string (if not possible to convert) or a timestamp in UTC format `(YYYY-MM-DD HH:MS:SS)`

In `my_date` the final part *...+02:00* means the (local) time is 2 hours ahead of UTC.

`my_utc_date = "2019-11-21 20:35:03"`

Comment: do you have any own ideas? did you try anything?

Comment: MIght I recommend fiverr?  Looks like a "please code this specific function for me, for free" request, IMO...  It doesn't look like you're trying to learn anything, you just want the solution, and there are sites for that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to achive your goal. Here I show you how to use [string.match](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-string.match) and [string patterns](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#6.4.1) to get the string elements. The rest is simple maths.

```
-- our input
local my_date = "2019-11-21T22:35:03.332+02:00"
-- we can just keep anything befor T as our date
local day = my_date:match("(.*)T")
-- now parse the UTC offset
local offsetH, offsetM = my_date:match("([%+%-]%d%d):(%d%d)")

-- apply sign to our minute offset
offsetM = offsetM * (tonumber(offsetH) > 0 and 1 or -1)

-- get time components
local h, m, s, ms = my_date:match("(%d%d):(%d%d):(%d%d).(%d%d%d)")

-- fix our and minute to get UTC
h = h - offsetH
m = m - offsetM
-- round seconds as we have microseconds in our input
s = math.floor(s + ms / 1000 + .5)

-- now put everything together with leading zeros
local my_utc_date = string.format("%s %02d:%02d:%02d", day, h, m, s)

print(my_utc_date)
```